# Websphere liberty profile 8.5.5.2 and jpa 1.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, websphere-liberty

[image: Error message]

How to deploy my application which is using jpa 1.0 to websphere server liberty profie 8.5.5.2 it is throwing out the following error when deploying to the server:
Applicaiton MyApp requires feature 'jpa-1.0', which is not supported by WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile.
Im using eclipse and i have checked project facets, set to jpa 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Liberty only has a jpa-2.0 feature in 8.5.5.2, which covers both JPA 1.0 and 2.0 specifications.  Try specifying "jpa-2.0" in your server.xml and see if you make more progress.

Comment: Yes. i already configured it as jpa-2.0 in the server configuration.

Comment: @suryas Try to uncheck JPA, in project facets, and just use persitence.xml in your project.